# Calling two function on onload is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I think I am doing some silly mistake, but somehow when I am calling two functions on onload, I am not getting expected result. Let me show the code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function greetUser() {
   alert('Hello users!');
}
function greetByName() {
   var name='';
   var name=prompt('Please enter your name','');
   if(name)
   {
     alert('Nice to meet you '+name);
     document.getElementById('rockImg').src='iRock_smile.png';
     setTimeout("document.getElementById('rockImg').src='iRock_normal.png';",5000);
   }

function setImageSize() {
     alert('hello');
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="setImageSize();greetUser();">
<img src="iRock_normal.png" id="rockImg" alt="iRock" onclick="greetByName();" />
</body>
</html>
```

I am not getting even a single alert. If I remove setImageSize(), code is working properly. So I think there might be some silly mistake. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have setImage function defined inside `greetByName` so it cannot find it in the global scope as it is defined within the scope of `greetByName()`, move it outside.

You can also make it less obtrusive by removing it from html and using `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function(){

   greetUser();
   setImageSize();
}

function greetUser() {
    alert('Hello users!');
}

function greetByName() {
    var name = '';
    var name = prompt('Please enter your name', '');
    if (name) {
        alert('Nice to meet you ' + name);
        document.getElementById('rockImg').src = 'iRock_smile.png';
        setTimeout("document.getElementById('rockImg').src='iRock_normal.png';", 5000);
    }
}

function setImageSize() {
    alert('hello');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`setImageSize()` is being declared in `greetByName()`, so it doesn't exist until `greetByName()` is called, let alone being accessible.

Declare it outside of `greetByName()`.